# AttributeError in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to build bot that prints a message when any client creates a channel.
I'm using discord.py version 1.2.3

```
import discord
import discord.ext
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def channel_create(channel):
    if discord.on_guild_channel_create():
       await print('the channel has been create ')
    return

client.run('TOKEN')
```

When I run it I get this error :

> `AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'on_guild_channel_create'`

any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), I would say that your function needs to override `on_guild_channel_create()` rather than call it as part of another function.

```
import discord
import discord.ext
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    await print('the channel has been create ')
    return

client.run('TOKEN')
```